# Calling a function stored in array produces "Unexpected trailing closure" in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I'm using Swift 1.2
I've got an array where I store my functions/closures.

Declaration of the array:

```
var pillFunctions: [(String, position: CGPoint) -> Void]
```

Declaration of function:

```
private func setPill1(number: String, position: CGPoint) -> Void {
    pillLabel1.text = number
    pill1.frame.origin = position
}
```

Storing functions in array (my class extends UIView):

```
required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    pillFunctions = [
            setPill1, setPill2, setPill3, setPill4, setPill5
    ]
}
```

Calling it:

```
pillFunctions[1]("213", position: CGPointMake(1.0, 2.0))
```

I'm new to Swift but I hoped this would work.
What am I missing here?

Thanks
Krystian

Comment: **Where exactly** do you get **which** error? Basically your code should work. Try if it compiles if you remove the `private` modifier.

Comment: sorry @idmean, I got the error "Unexpected trailing closure" when calling the pillFunctions[1] function.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a several mistakes.

First of all, I've had to initialize the array:

```
var pillFunctions: [(String, position: CGPoint) -> Void] = []
```

And the init function of my class was incorrect:

```
required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    self.pillFunctions = [ self.setPill1, self.setPill2, self.setPill3, self.setPill4, self.setPill5 ]
}
```

After these two changes, it started to work.

I'm not sure this is the best approach, only because "it works", doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: This looks more correct. Actually your initializer was correct, you just did not initialize `pillFunctions` before calling the super initializer. It is typical of the Swift compiler to produce errors at random locations if there is a mistake in an initializer.